# Access is denied error when running cmd as different user

Tags: permissions, conda, windows-server, multi-user

In our organisation we often automate tasks using Windows Task Scheduler. In a typical scenario, we have a bat file that calls python to execute a piece of code. After adopting virtual environments in Python we ran into an issue where we get an "Access is denied" error when calling the bat file using a service account.

To reproduce the error I opened cmd as a different user and provided our service account's credentials. The service account has sufficient permissions to navigate to the directory of conda.bat but gives an error when I try to run the bat file:
[image]

I also tried to run the bat file as a different user, then I get the following error:
[image]

[image]

Here are the contents of the bat file:
[image]

The operating system in question is Windows Server 2016 Standard.

Any idea why we are getting this error and how we can resolve it?

Comment: Hi K J, thank you for your response. The example to change directory to a different user's desktop was just an example to reproduce the "access is denied" error. In reality we want to open python (by running C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat) as a different user, which gives the same error. I will update my post to make it more clear.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the conda.bat file contents in the problem description.

Comment: The problem has been solved by creating a scheduled task and ticking the "Run with highest privileges" box. Thank you K J for your inputs and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by creating a scheduled task and ticking the "Run with highest privileges" box:

[image]